# intermec pd43 not able to print characters like é

Tags: java, printing, intermec

I use java to prepare intermec code (Direct Protocol). Special characters like é,ô,Ö are not printing, rather it prints these char.s as û`

"FONT \"Swiss 721 BT\", 24, 10\n" +

"DIR 4\n"+

"ALIGN 7\n" +

"NASC 34\n" +

"PRPOS 40,40\n" +

"PRTXT \"é è ô Ö ç à î\"\n" +

"PRINTFEED\n" +

"CLEAR\n";

Verified that the font is installed on my intermec printer.

Comment: This question is off-topic as it is not directly related to programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use Java to create the string to send to the printer, then you likely are sending UTF-8 encoded data to the printer.  So you must set the printer to accept UTF-8 characters using the NASC command as follows:  NASC "UTF-8".